# grouping a pandas DataFrame with predifined groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am wondering, how to efficiently do something like `groupby` when I have predefined groups, and elements might belong to multiple groups at the same time.

Suppose, I have the following `DataFrame`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [0, 2, 4]}, index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

```py
   value
A      0
B      2
C      4
```

and I have the following predefined groups, which might be overlapping and of different size:

```py
groups = {'group 1': ['A', 'B'],
          'group 2': ['A', 'B', 'C']}
```

Now, I want to perform a function on the `DataFrame` groups. For example, I want to calculate the mean of `value` for each group.

I was thinking to create an intermediate "expanded" `DataFrame` on which I could run a `groupby`:

```py
intermediate_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'group', 'value'])
intermediate_df['value'] = intermediate_df['value'].astype(float)

for group, members in groups.items():
    for id_ in members:
        row = pd.Series([id_, group, df.at[id_, 'value']],
                        index=['id', 'group', 'value'])
        intermediate_df = intermediate_df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

```py
  id    group  value
0  A  group 1    0.0
1  B  group 1    2.0
2  A  group 2    0.0
3  B  group 2    2.0
4  C  group 2    4.0
```

Then, I could do

```py
intermediate_df.groupby('group').mean()
```

which would give me the desired result:

```py
         value
group         
group 1    1.0
group 2    2.0
```

Of course, the way I create this intermediate `DataFrame` is absolutely inefficient. What would be an efficient solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your `intermediate_df` with [`Pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and a list comprehension:

```
intermediate_df = pd.concat([df.loc[v].assign(group=k) for k, v in groups.items()])
```

[OUT]

```
   value    group
A      0  group 1
B      2  group 1
A      0  group 2
C      4  group 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit try for uneven groups:

```
pd.DataFrame().from_dict(groups, orient='index').T.stack().map(df.squeeze()).mean(level=1)
```

You can do it this way also:

```
pd.DataFrame(groups).stack().map(df.squeeze()).mean(level=1)
```

Output:

```
group 1    1
group 2    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I forgot to specify that the groups might be of different size. Then, your answer does not work any more, but this was my fault. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Building on previous answers, I use list comprehension for an `intermediate_df`

```py
intermediate_df = pd.DataFrame([[group, id_] for group, members in groups.items() for id_ in members], 
                               columns=['group', 'id']).merge(df, left_on='id', right_index=True)
```

This seems to be the fastest solution compared to the other answers:

```py
n=10000
m=1000
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.normal(size=n)}, index=np.arange(n).astype(str))
groups = {str(i): list(df.sample(5).index) for i in range(m)}
```

```py
%%timeit
intermediate_df = pd.concat([df.loc[members].assign(group=group) for group, members in groups.items()])
intermediate_df.groupby('group').mean()

948 ms ± 63.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(groups).stack().map(df.squeeze()).mean(level=1)

42.4 ms ± 183 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
intermediate_df = pd.DataFrame([[group, id_] for group, members in groups.items() for id_ in members], 
                               columns=['group', 'id']).merge(df, left_on='id', right_index=True)
intermediate_df.groupby('group').mean()

6.13 ms ± 50.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```